# Can we use user-defined (non-scalar) SQL-types for ORM?

Tags: sql, oracle, orm

I'm wondering if its possible to do ORM using SQL.2003 object types (aka STRUCTs, aka non-scalar types).

The idea behind that is to avoid the ["n+1 selects" problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem) by retrieving complete objects directly from the database. Sort of eager "FetchMode.JOIN", but **in the database**.

Are there any ORM frameworks fpor Java or .Net which support SQL object types at all?

At least JDBC has the [getObject method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject%28int%29) and I've also found an example of [user-defined types in ADO.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131066.aspx)

As an Oracle developer, I may be biased towards database-centric approaches and I also didn't use ORM before. But Oracle features [Object Views](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c14ordb.htm#439884) which let you compose objects from several relational tables. I bet these could be magnitudes faster than pulling all those single records out of the database, let alone issuing n+1 selects.

Comment: Yes, Object Views in the DB are orders of magnitude faster than pulling the data out of the DB. Have you looked at Java inside the Oracle DB and if it can read native Object Views as Java non-scalar types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the developer of [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org), and I am striving to make jOOQ exactly what you need. jOOQ currently supports any of these Oracle features:

- All types of SQL constructs, including nested selects, aliasing, union operations, etc
- Stored procedures and functions
- Packages
- VARRAY types (mapped to Java arrays)
- UDT types (mapped to Java objects)
- combinations thereof

More support will be added in the near future, for advanced Oracle concepts such as

- TABLE types
- CURSOR, REF CURSOR types
- Other collection types

Object views are currently not supported in the way you described, but I'll clearly put them on the roadmap.

See more on http://www.jooq.org

Comment: Lukas, thanks for your reply. I've finally looked into jOOQ, LINQ and other ORM tools as well, trying to figure out how they relate to each other and what might be the pros and cons. After all I'll try to convince the customer to go with ADO and/or DAO and keep the midlle tier as thin as possible. If they still want to go ORM we'll have to avoid UDTs as they are not supported equally across platforms and databases. Maybe jOOQ will still be an option then, but I certainly don't have the expertise to make them not use Hibernate.

Comment: @hal9000: Thanks for the feedback. Hibernate is an excellent database abstraction library, too. It just depends on the use-case...

Comment: Just looked at jOOQ. It definitely solves the n+1 problem. SQL business logic in Java objects. Great project shows great promise!